# Launching the latest version of a clicOnce C# application console, and pass arguments

Tags: c#, console, arguments, launching

My colleague and I have to write a software together. He only knows Delphi and I only know C# (I'm not a software engineer) The application is hardware measurement. I write the hardware routines and he writes the front end.
So the two softwares must work together. The best solution would be a DLL, but we don't know how to write it. The solution I found is a console application on my side, the application writes the measurement results to a file (old method, but I'm 61 years old!) and the front end runs the console application and reads the output file. This works.
The problem is that every time I update my software, click once install creates a new directory, and the front end doesn't know what the latest version is. Of course, there is a workaround.
The next problem is that the front end has to pass parameters. Of course, it can write a command file.
A better way is to pass arguments to the console application. The only way I found to call the latest version is to use the Windows menu shortcut. But it seems that it is not possible to pass arguments to it.

Questions:
-Calling the .exe in the app/2.0 directory directly with arguments, but how do the front end can determine what is the latest version installed?
-Calling the shortcut, but what about the arguments?
The process must be fast, because the console application is called every minute.
Any better ideas? (of course with limited knowledge!).  I'm also wondering what the difference is between a console application and a command line.
Thank a lot.
Denis

Comment: It is able to export a C# dll to COM so that Delphi can import it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com